# 気がつく and 気づく particle usage?

Tags: particle-が

For 気がつく, since the が particle is always attached to 気, making it the subject of the clause, so you can't say 私がことに気がつくbut 私はことに気がつく. But I wonder if you can make 私 the subject if you use 気づく? since 気づくseems like a complete verb itself, rather than just omitting the particles from 気がつく. So can you say 私がことに気づく?

Comment: Are you thinking that you can't use が twice in a sentence? That's not the case.